# Getting error in Inline if condition in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get a string value like below

```
string bsgrpval;
bsgrpval =
    ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Pricing_IncludeALLBaseLineGroup"]=="False"
        ? string.Empty
        : bsgrp.ForEach(x => bsgrpval = bsgrpval + x.Value.ToString() + ",");
```

I am getting following error:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is
>   no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'void'

Can somebody help me in this?

Answer (score 7):

You can't do an inline if that way. `List.ForEach` doesn't return anything.

```
condition ? x : y;
```

`x` and `y` must return something and be the same type (or have an implicit cast).

Perhaps you want a string join.

```
bsgrpval = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Pricing_IncludeALLBaseLineGroup"]=="False"
        ? string.Empty
        : string.Join(',', 
             bsgrp.Select(x => bsgrpval = bsgrpval + x.Value.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: +1 - OP, Both results from the tertiary operator must be able to return the same type: aka `true ? "Hello World" : new Object()` is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Error occurs because `.ForEach` doesn't returns string. Do with `.Aggregate`:

```
string bsgrpval;  
bsgrpval=ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Pricing_IncludeALLBaseLineGroup"] == "False" string.Empty : bsgrp.Aggregate((acc, item) => string.Concat(acc, ",", item.Value.ToString()));
```

Comment: Foreach returns the string correctly if i do it separately.Only if i give in inline if condition i am getting that error.

Comment: ForEach returns void http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx. You should use method like Aggregate to return string in statement above.